# How to prevent certain 'Bulk' labeled email from skipping the inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail, I have the smart labels 'Bulk', 'Forums', 'Notifications'. I have a daily reminder email sent everyday that is now getting marked as 'Bulk' which is a correct categorization, however I want these to still show up in my inbox, without all the other 'Bulk' mail also showing in the inbox.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there wasn't a way, even with re-categorizing like the blog post suggests, to get messages to not end up in the Bulk label. Disabling smart filters and writing my own specific filters to move messages to a "Bulk" folder was the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a explanation regarding smart labels and other labels http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/03/gmail-smart-labels.html

It appears you can make sure that some don't skip the inbox.