# Force emails from specific senders to stay in inbox instead of getting smart labeled by Gmail

Tags: gmail, notifications, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, priority-inbox

I periodically get *very* important notifications from a pair of addresses. For reasons that elude me, they have recently started skipping the inbox and going to notifications. I would like them to stay in my inbox. How do I force emails from `*@example.edu` and `#@example.net` to stay in my inbox? I can't label them as inbox in filters.

I found [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/gmail-filters-labels-force-email-to-stay-in-inbox) but the method does not seem to apply because my emails are automatically smart filtered.

I also found [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22965/how-to-prevent-certain-bulk-labeled-email-from-skipping-the-inbox) but I don't understand how to create my own smart label like they describe.

Comment: What do you mean by "going to notifications"?